# How to move a targeted object to the front of an indexed array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object, multidimensional-array

I have an indexed array of objects like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => St Object
        (
            [pId] => 6590153
            [prId] => 5371
            [expirationDate] => 2018-07-10 23:59:59           
            [creationDate] => 2018-01-10 11:58:29
            [pkid] => 12345
            [parentObj] => s Object
                (
                    [id] => 654250
                    [userID] => 776134
                    [pkid] ] => 12345
        )
     [ur] => 5899
         [overAgeRate] => 1.00
    )

    [1] => St Object
        (
            [pId] => 6590154
            [prId] => 5371
            [expirationDate] => 2018-07-10 23:59:59           
            [creationDate] => 2018-01-10 11:58:29
            [pkid] => 12346
            [parentObj] => s Object
                (
                    [id] => 654250
                    [userID] => 776134
                    [pkid] ] => 12346
        )
     [ur] => 58
         [overAgeRate] => 1.00
    )
)
```

I want to rearrange the array based on my needle value. For example `$needle=12346`.

Based on this value the second object needs to become the first element. the result array will be:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => St Object
            (
                [pId] => 6590154
                [prId] => 5371
                [expirationDate] => 2018-07-10 23:59:59           
                [creationDate] => 2018-01-10 11:58:29
                [pkid] => 12346
                [parentObj] => s Object
                    (
                        [id] => 654250
                        [userID] => 776134
                        [pkid] ] => 12346
            )
         [ur] => 58
             [overAgeRate] => 1.00
        )

        [1] => St Object
            (
                [pId] => 6590153
                [prId] => 5371
                [expirationDate] => 2018-07-10 23:59:59           
                [creationDate] => 2018-01-10 11:58:29
                [pkid] => 12345
                [parentObj] => s Object
                    (
                        [id] => 654250
                        [userID] => 776134
                        [pkid] ] => 12345
            )
         [ur] => 5899
             [overAgeRate] => 1.00
        )
    )
```

How can I do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods will move your target object to the front of the array if it exists and silently move nothing if the target is not found.

Method #1 ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YpMdu))

```
$pkid='12346';
usort($array,function($a,$b)use($pkid){          // put needle into function scope
        if($a->pkid!=$pkid && $b->pkid!=$pkid){  // neither object matches needle
            return 0;                            // no move
        }
        return $a->pkid==$pkid ? -1 : 1;         // $a or $b matches; appropriately move
    });
var_export($array);
```

Method #2: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NfrSm))

```
$pkid='12346';
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    if($v->pkid== $pkid){                        // found the needle
        unset($array[$k]);                       // remove object from array
        array_unshift($array,$v);                // reinsert it at the front (reindex keys)
        break;                                   // no reason to continue iterating
    }
}
var_export($array);
```

Comment: I have used below code, it works fine. 
$pkid='12346';
foreach ( $arr as $k=>$v ) {
   $pkId = $v->pkid;
   if($pkId == $pkid)
   {    
   unset($arr[$k]);       
       array_unshift($arr,$v);
       break;
   }

Comment: Swapping `array_splice()` for `unset()` is certainly a better call.  I've updated my answer.  I don't recommend using case-sensitivity to differentiate between similar variables -- it will make your code harder to read.  I also have another principle that dictates that single-use variables should not be declared -- I didn't declare `$pkId` in my updated answer for this reason.